Use Vuex and Pinia Store in Quasar
I am working on a Quasar app that uses Vuex. I need to use some modules that use Pinia so I would need to instantiate Pinia on my app as well.
My problem is, how do I instantiate both Vuex and Pinia stores in Quasar?
Here is my store\index.js which instantiates the Vuex Store:
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { importedVuexStoreModule } from 'sample-store-module'

export default function () {
  const Store = createStore({
    modules: {
      importedVuexStoreModule 
    },
    state: {},
    getters: {},
    mutations: {}
  })
  return Store
}

I know I can just export both like this:
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import { importedVuexStoreModule } from 'sample-store-module'


const pinia = createPinia()

const store = createStore({
  modules: {
    importedVuexStoreModule 
  },
  state: {},
  getters: {},
  mutations: {}
})

export { pinia, store }

But my problem is - Quasar auto-generates the app.js (every time the app is ran) which calls the store:
import { Quasar } from 'quasar'
import { markRaw } from 'vue'
import RootComponent from 'app/src/App.vue'

import createStore from 'app/src/store/index'
import createRouter from 'app/src/router/index'

export default async function (createAppFn, quasarUserOptions) {
  // Create the app instance.
  // Here we inject into it the Quasar UI, the router & possibly the store.
  const app = createAppFn(RootComponent)
  app.config.performance = true
  app.use(Quasar, quasarUserOptions)
  
    const store = typeof createStore === 'function'
      ? await createStore({})
      : createStore
    
      // obtain Vuex injection key in case we use TypeScript
      const { storeKey } = await import('app/src/store/index')

  const router = markRaw(
    typeof createRouter === 'function'
      ? await createRouter({store})
      : createRouter
  )
  
    // make router instance available in store    
      store.$router = router

  // Expose the app, the router and the store.
  // Note that we are not mounting the app here, since bootstrapping will be
  // different depending on whether we are in a browser or on the server.
  return {
    app,
    store, storeKey,
    router
  }
}

How can I make it instantiate both Vuex and Pinia without modifying the app.js file?
To also add, we are doing things by batches and so I wont be able to upgrade the app to use just Pinia (too much work and too little time).
Using Vue 3, if it matters.
Thanks!

It's unclear what is the problem. Do what's necessary to use them in quasar separately. They aren't related, you don't need them in the same module as { pinia, store }. They even don't share a convention for file structure (src/store for vuex vs /src/stores for pinia)

Pinia is literally what Vuex 5 would've been, it's just rebranded.  You're basically trying to use two versions of the same library.  Consider just using Pinia.
